# Seems like my Geth node is stuck in block 12964999? (pre-London fork block)

Tags: go-ethereum

So I restarted today my Geth node and is repeating this:

> INFO [08-07|14:40:34.090] Looking for peers ----------------------- peercount=2 tried=30 static=0

I checked in the Geth console a couple of things. First I tried `admin.peers` and the result was an array of 10 nodes (not 2 as it says in the log message, I don't understand why).

Then I tried checking `eth.blockNumber` and this is the most strange thing, I got a value of `12964999`, exactly the last block before the London fork. This makes me think I should initialize Geth with some sort of parameter? I've been waiting for a couple of hours and is not able to find more than 2 peers. This is how I'm currently initializing Geth:

> geth --syncmode=fast --cache=58000 --ws --ws.port 8181 --ws.api
> "eth,net,web3,txpool" --txpool.globalslots 512 --txpool.accountqueue 0
> --txpool.globalqueue 0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Apparently I had to upgrade Geth to the latest version 1.10.6